# NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster

Tags: eks

I'm setting up an EKS cluster using https://github.com/ManagedKube/kubernetes-ops

and, based on that code, when I do a `terraform apply` I'm getting a `NodeCreationFailure` error.

Specifically:

```
│ Error: error waiting for EKS Node Group (staging:staging-ng12022040211190144860000000d) to create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: 1 error occurred:
│   * i-0d5c42031eaf061ff, i-0d9a073240fd29c45: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster
```

Admittedly, that's not much code, but does anyone have any pointers on where to start debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I incurred the same problem during one of my deployments.

This happens due to the **Networking issue** of the EKS cluster. Assuming that you are working in AWS, follow the following  steps to debug this problem:

1. Check if your security groups are correctly configured correctly to your Nodes.
2. If the EKS is present in the public sub-nets, check its connectivity to internet gateway and is able to access the internet.
3. If Eks is present in the private sub-net, check the connectivity with NAT gateway and that NAT gateway is able to access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past where the nodes couldn't join the cluster.
The cause of this was a mismatch in security groups, the nodes and the EKS control plane weren't allowed to talk to each other and therefore timed out.

Comment: without some context to corroborate that these two situations are related, it's difficult to be sure that this is an answer. Have you got some output you can share, or other information, to link this answer to the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue, it was solved by creating another nat gateway and choosing public subnet and attaching that new nat gateway in routable to my private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has listed a set of reasons it could make Node groups to fail joining a cluster. Refer, https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-worker-nodes-cluster
I was able to understand that one of my security groups rejected the comms between Control Plane and the worker node. This troubleshooting was possible using System Automation - TroubleshootingEKSNode.